# Column with dynamic width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need a grip with two cols, the left col needs a min-width of 300px the right col shall use the remaining width, similar to css-calc. Is this possible or shall I write custom CSS.

```
calc(100% - 300px)
```

HTML

```
 <div class="col-2"></div>
 <div class="col-10"></div>
```

Comment: Why not use a display `table` and `table-cell` instead?

Comment: you mean without bootstrap?

Comment: Yes. I mean you don't need a responsive grid system for this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also achievable with flexbox, as follows:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  height: 30px;
}

.col-2 {
  flex: 2;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.col-10 {
  flex: 10;
}

.bg-blue {
  background: blue;
}

.bg-green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child col-2 bg-blue"></div>
  <div class="child col-10 bg-green"></div>
</div>
```

Snippet also available in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNLwLj).

Learn more about Flexbox [from here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Read also the [CanIUse page](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for flexbox.

Comment: The downvote made me come back to the answer and realise something went wrong with my snippet, so I corrected it. Thank you for the _subtle_ remark.